# How to write this anonymous block?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use an anonymous block for a double update, but it does not work for me.
What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE  
   v_voucher NUMBER(10) := 4329;
BEGIN

   UPDATE PRODUCTION 
   SET 
     UND_PROD = 0,
     UND_DET = 0
   WHERE 
     VOUCHER = v_voucher;
 
   UPDATE DET_PRODUCTION 
   SET 
     UND_GOOD = 0,
     UND_BAD = 0
   WHERE 
     VOUCHER = v_voucher;
 
END;
```

> ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
> null pragma raise return select update while with
> [an identifier] [a double-quoted delimited-identifier]
> [a bind variable] continue close current delete fetch lock
> insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
> merge pipe purge

Comment: Do you have any code before or after this anonimous block?

Comment: I created table like you have and after executin code i got: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your code as such, but you seem to have a hidden character that is causing the problem.

If I copy the code from the edit window and dump what is in there the line before the second update has `C2A0`.

```
select dump ('  WHERE VOUCHER = v_voucher;
     
    UPDATE DET_PRODUCTION SET 
', 1016) from dual;

DUMP('WHEREVOUCHER=V_VOUCHER; UPDATEDET_PRODUCTIONSET',1016)                                                                                                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=60 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 9,57,48,45,52,45,20,56,4f,55,43,48,45,52,20,3d,20,76,5f,76,6f,75,63,68,65,72,3b,a,9,c2,a0,a,9,55,50,44,41,54,45,20,44,45,54,5f,50,52,4f,44,55,43,54,49,4f,4e,20,53,45,54,20,a
                                                                                                                         ^^^^^
```

The simplest way to fix it is probably to select all the text from the semicolon after the first update, to immediately before the second update, and delete it - replacing it with a fresh newline or two.

Or copy the rendered block from your question and run that - the rogue character isn't a problem once the raw code (which you can only see by editing) has been processed as Markdown.

Not sure where this would have come from; perhaps you wrote this in an external program like Word and it added special characters, as it has a habit of doing...

Comment: Thank you Alex, effectively there was a hidden character I had this code saved in Microsoft OneNote and this program had added a blank space that caused the error.
I came to think that it was badly written, but I did not see the error.